# JavaScript library for real-time sliding bubble/scatter graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, plot, scatter-plot

I'm looking for a library with the following features:

- Real-time sliding right-to-left graph
- Graph consisting of bubbles of different sizes and colors
- The bubbles should have labels that slide with them

The closest one I've found is Epoch by Fastly (https://fastly.github.io/epoch/). It has a nice scatter graph (but no labels) and nice and smooth real-time graphs, but no scatter graphs for the real-time part. I've considered modifying it, but the code paths to draw static graphs and real-time graphs are completely different and it seems hard to add a new real-time graph.

D3.js seems too low-level for my current use case and since the use-case seems trivial enough I hope I'm missing an obvious alternative library that will be easy to use.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `Rickshaw`

site: http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/

github:https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw

here's what you need: just select scatter

http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/extensions.html